# Fatal Error : call to a member function getCfg () on a non-object

Tags: php, joomla

Hi i have uploaded a template on a website i have created using joomla and when i apply the template and visit my website i get the following error,

**Fatal Error : call to a member function Fatal Error : call to a member function getCfg () on a non-object in /home/a7751589/public_html/templates/themza_j15_11/index.php on line 21.**

the code on the index.php line 21 is as below.

```
$sliderVars['directionNav']=($this->params->get('sliderVars_directionNav')==='true' or $this->params->get('sliderVars_directionNav')==='false')?$this->params->get('sliderVars_directionNav'):'true';
```

please advise what i need to do to make this work,

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct line? There's no "getCfg()" calls in this line.

Comment: It's not a clear question!nobody can help you just by 1 line code!

Comment: What object are you using "$this" on in index.php?

Comment: please share more code to understand your mistake and make it workable. Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

i recommend to checking compatibility of your theme with components...

check its  http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=637126

Answer (score 0):

Agree with GkDreamz - the "...*J15*..." part in your template name makes me think it's a 1.5 template that you're probably installing on a new 2.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I noticed this in the PHP script:

```
global $mainframe;
```

Bear in mind that starting with Joomla 2.5, `$mainframe` is no longer using `global`, so it should be this:

```
$mainframe = & JFactory::getApplication();
```